# RESTful service doesn't work with glassFish

Tags: java, rest, glassfish

I'm trying to develop a RESTful service on IntelliJ with glassFish 4.1.1 and pretty simple HelloWorld service, but I don't understand why it doesn't work.
I configured the IntelliJ IDEA as need according to their tutorial -

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-restful-web-service.html#c2545482

and created a run configuration as it should be -

[image: run configurations]

The JDK in the project structure -

[image]

When I ran the code I got this -

> C:\glassfish4\glassfish\bin\asadmin.bat start-domain domain1
>   GlassFish requires Java SE version 6.  Your JDK is version 0
>   "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9\bin\java.exe" -Dfile.encoding=windows-1255 -classpath C:\Users\nirkov\AppData\Local\Temp\classpath1369926740.jar com.intellij.javaee.oss.process.JavaeeProcess 53923 com.intellij.javaee.oss.glassfish.agent.Glassfish31Agent
>   Detected server admin port: 4848
>   [2019-11-06 02:34:46,592] Artifact RESTfulGameServices:war exploded: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
>   Detected server http port: 8080

Where the line -

> GlassFish requires Java SE version 6. Your JDK is version 0

seems like an error.

what can be the problem?

Comment: What does java --version show?

Answer (score -1):

You should download and install the java jdk.

You'll find the link below :

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Comment: I use JDK 9 as it seems in the project structure.

Comment: SDK and JDK are not the same thing !